# Controlling Tab Keyword That KeyPressEvent Returns

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QPlainText` in my app . When clicks this `QPlainText` or entering a character from keyboard , I call a method that gets information from database called `get_info()`.This is how I use this method:

```
self.plainTxtPatientDiagnosis.keyPressEvent = functools.partial(self.get_info)
self.plainTxtPatientDiagnosis.mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.get_info)
```

and set text to `QPlainText`.

```
 def get_info(self, event):
        if event.key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
            self.chkboxPatientStatus.setFocus()

        ......(Getting info from database codes)
```

What I want to do is when pressing Tab Key , focus another `QCheckBox` object.If I enter tab keyword from keyboard gets information from database and set QPlainText object but does not focus `QCheckbox` object. And if I press mouse an error occured :

```
AttributeError: 'QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'key'
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case why you need partial itself ?, you are not passing anything and you are not connection the signal.

```
self.plainTxtPatientDiagnosis.keyPressEvent.connect(self.get_info)
self.plainTxtPatientDiagnosis.mousePressEvent.connect(self.get_info)
```

Don't work this ?

Comment: It works . But I can't control Tab keyword . I want to focus a widget if Tab key pressed